# How to avoid if/else when the if condition can be calculated in compile time

Tags: c++

For example:

```
if (sizeof(long) == 4)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

I think there should be an elegant way to avoid this kind of if/else, maybe something like std::conditional, but I can't find. thanks :)

Comment: You might want to look at [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: Also there's [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) in C++11 and above. Although In C++11 it's pretty limited and not suitable for generic code, it's possible to perform various calculations

Comment: In the optimized output, is it there anymore?  Why do you care?

Comment: As it *will* be calculated at compile time, you are *already* avoiding it.

Comment: @Yakk and EJP,  yes, you are right, it can be optimized if I turn on optimization, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps referring to tag dispatching?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void
process(std::true_type)
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(long) == 4\n";
}

void
process(std::false_type)
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(long) != 4\n";
}

int
main()
{
    process(std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(long) == 4>{});
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that std::integral_constant is a part of C++11

Comment: Perhaps.  I'm still searching for the question...  Fwiw, in 2016 I no longer assume that C++ refers to C++98 or C++03.  :-)

Comment: :-) However in a project dedicated to consumer WinCE-based electronics we're still bound to MSVC 2005 :/

Comment: @user3159253:  Ouch!  I've never really understood how clinging to decade-old technology increases quality.  Though I can certainly understand the extreme opposite position that living on the bleeding edge is risky.